# How can I get distance from given path value in Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have integrated Google Maps JavaScript API in my application. I need to calculate travelled distance by given path.

Path is like,

```
var path = [
            {lat: 36.579, lng: -118.292},
            {lat: 36.606, lng: -118.0638},
            {lat: 36.433, lng: -117.951},
            {lat: 36.588, lng: -116.943},
            {lat: 36.34, lng: -117.468},
            {lat: 36.24, lng: -116.832}];
```

Using above value need to calculate distance. Give me your valuable idea.

Comment: Distance from where to where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 spherical geometry distance methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#spherical), the "points" need to be [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) objects, not [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral) objects.

There are at least four options:

1. convert your array of google.maps.LatLngLiterals to google.maps.LatLng objects.

```
var path = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(36.579, -118.292),
      new google.maps.LatLng(36.606, -118.0638),
      new google.maps.LatLng(36.433, -117.951),
      new google.maps.LatLng(36.588, -116.943),
      new google.maps.LatLng(36.34, -117.468),
      new google.maps.LatLng(36.24, -116.832)];
var distanceInMeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path);
```

2. create a google.maps.Polyline with your array of google.maps.LatLngLiterals, then call `.getPath` on that polyline.

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: path
});
var distanceInMeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(polyline.getPath());
```

3. convert your coordinates to google.maps.LatLng and call compute distance on each pair, accumulating the distance.

```
var distanceInMeters = 0;
for (var i=0; i<path.length-1; i++) {
    distanceInMeters += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(new google.maps.LatLng(path[i].lat, path[i].lng),new google.maps.LatLng(path[i+1].lat, path[i+1].lng));
}
```

4. write your own version of the haversine formula that takes an array of LatLngLiterals